# Differences in SQL Expressions and results

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello everyone as I continue to learn about SQL I have learned that the following are three different expression I would expect to return the same result.

There are four tables I'm working with the two that this query involves are

```
SHIPMENTS with the columns (SUPPLIERNO, PARTNO,PRJECTNO,QUANTITY)
PROJECT (PROJECTNO, NAME, CITY)
```

The question is find the name of the project where supplier S1 and S2 do not ship any parts to it

```
QUERY # 1
SELECT distinct PROJECTS.NAME
FROM PROJECTS, SHIPMENTS
WHERE PROJECTS.PROJECTNO NOT IN(
  SELECT distinct SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO
  FROM SHIPMENTS
  WHERE SUPPLIERNO <= 'S2');
```

This query returns the expected result there is one project that neither ships a part to.

Query 2

```
SELECT distinct PROJECTS.NAME
FROM PROJECTS, SHIPMENTS
WHERE PROJECTS.PROJECTNO NOT IN(
  SELECT distinct SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO
  FROM SHIPMENTS
  WHERE SUPPLIERNO <= 'S2')  
AND SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO = PROJECTS.PROJECTNO;
```

This returns no results where all I wanted to do was make sure the relationship was known.

And QUERY 3

```
SELECT distinct PROJECTS.NAME
FROM PROJECTS, SHIPMENTS
WHERE PROJECTS.PROJECTNO NOT IN(
  SELECT distinct SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO
  FROM SHIPMENTS
  WHERE SUPPLIERNO = 'S2'
  AND SUPPLIERNO = 'S1');
```

This returns all the project names.

To me these all look the same.  What am I missing?

Our professor did not explain why these would all evaluate differently

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for editing my post how do you get it to highlight that way?

Comment: indent four space or place enclose your script between grave accent mark `

Answer (score 0):

Your query #1 contain two table but were not connected.

```
FROM PROJECTS, SHIPMENTS
```

While query #2 this two table where connected in

```
AND SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO = PROJECTS.PROJECTNO
```

Lastly query #3, the sub-query contain a filter for a specific supplierno.

```
Sub-query:

 SELECT distinct SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO
 FROM SHIPMENTS
 WHERE SUPPLIERNO = 'S2'
  AND SUPPLIERNO = 'S1'
```

**Update**

The first query did not used any fields from your second table `SHIPMENTS` within

```
SELECT distinct PROJECTS.NAME
FROM PROJECTS, SHIPMENTS
```

Comment: OK I guess then how come the first query gives me the correct response then?

Comment: The first query gave the expected response because there was not very much data in your database.  It was a fluke.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you are missing is that this subquery:

```
SELECT distinct SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO
FROM SHIPMENTS
WHERE SUPPLIERNO = 'S2'
AND SUPPLIERNO = 'S1'
```

probably returns no rows.  So your query 3 will either throw an error or return every possible row.

Also, my personal theory is, "when in doubt, look at your data."  For query 2, take away the subquery.  Just run this:

```
SELECT distinct PROJECTS.NAME
FROM PROJECTS, SHIPMENTS
WHERE SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO = PROJECTS.PROJECTNO;
```

You said you wanted to check the relationship, this will do it.

**Edit starts here**

If this comment, "There are 5 suppliers in the table all S1, S2 ... I should have included that in my original question", alludes to my initial statement, my point was not sufficiently clear.  A record can have only one value in a field.  So if the value is S1, it can't also be S2.  Maybe that subquery should have been:

```
SELECT distinct SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO
FROM SHIPMENTS
WHERE SUPPLIERNO = 'S2'
or SUPPLIERNO = 'S1'   -- changed the and to an or
```

or this:

```
SELECT distinct SHIPMENTS.PROJECTNO
FROM SHIPMENTS
WHERE SUPPLIERNO in ( 'S2', 'S1')
```

Comment: Sorry I might have said that wrong I meant that I wanted to make sure the query know the proper relationship.  But that last query would not get me what I need.  There are 5 suppliers in the table all S1, S2 ...  I should have included that in my original question.

Comment: My comment was in response to the the suggested query that did not include the subquery.  I think I understand why this did not execute properly now.  I'm still unclear as to why adding the relationship specification alters the result.  And Thankyou for the help

Answer (score 0):

In all three queries, you have a common filter, in that the PROJECTNO should not be found in the SHIPMENT table. However the 3 queries are not the same at all. The code doesn't vary muchbut there is some subtle differences which have large consequences:

In Q1 you do not add any additional restrictions to the code, and therefore it will return all PROJECTS with no SHIPMENTS.

In Q2, you add the requirement, that the PROJECTNO returned must be the same as the SHIPMENT.PROJECTNO, but you are looking for PROJECTS without SHIPMENTS and therefore this criteria is never met and thus you have no data being returned.

In Q3, you specify that a SUPPLIERNO should be S1 and S2, however this is not possible and therefore no SHIPMENTS are returned from the sub query and you therefore get all PROJECTS listed as if no SHIPMENTS have taken place.